# Communicating between PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb

I have a PHP-built user system and an instant messaging system built with node, socket.io and jQuery on a MongoDB database.

I'd like to interface between the two. For example, users can sign in with their account and post messages from their account. I know in theory how this would be done. However, couldn't the user just change their user ID as it is being passed from the $_SESSION to the jQuery and thus imitate another user?

What is the correct way to do what I am describing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are already many Q&A on this topic. Which ones have you consulted?

Comment: If they are logged in and you're sending request through jQuery, then at the backend get sender's $_SESSION, identify it and send back response.

Comment: The session is created on the server when the user attempts to log on using the correct authentication (e.g. password) for the user. This session is bound to the connection, and is no longer identified by a user id. If you have no authentication, then of course, anyone can spoof as another user, even without fancy session vars.

Comment: The user does not have direct access to $_SESSION

Comment: My issue is passing the session variable, say the user's ID to the jQuery server-side script that handles message posting. How do I pass it to the server.js?